# Printing a class instance results in None if I change the class member values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have run into a problem I can't explain:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, rid, title):
        self.rid = rid
        self.title = title
        self.b = []

    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(other) == B:
            self.b += [other]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rid + ' - ' + self.title

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, rid, title):
        self.rid = rid
        self.title = title

b = B('123', 'abc')
a = A('345', 'cde')

print(a)

a += b

print(a)
```

The first print results in the expected output:

```
345 - cde
```

However, the second print (after the adding of b) results in:

```
None
```

Why is that? I am not changing the rid or the title of `a` nor do I create new and uninitialized instance called `a`, or am I?

Comment: you have to return the result from `__add__`

Comment: I would have to `return self`?

Comment: Consider making `__add__` return a new instance of `A` instead of modifying `self` in-place (use `__iadd__` for that).

Comment: You probably meant to have `B` extend `A` right? (or, alternatively, to define `__add__` in class `B` as well).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wanted `b` be added in the list `a.b`.

Comment: @chepner: what would the benefit of that be? Also I thought I was already modifying self in place...

Comment: You are modifying it in place, but that's what `__iadd__` is for. Would you want `c = a + b` to modify `a`?

Comment: @chepner: if my original `a` is list anyway by `a += b` what would be the difference of not modifying in place? Will it be a garbage collection issue?

Comment: Let's use a list as an example: if `list.__add__` modified it in place, would you really expect `a = []; c = a + [1]; print(a)` to output `[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `a += b` is a shorthand for: `a = a.__add__(b)`

As your `__add__()` method returns `None` that means you will assign `None` to `a`.